# Calculate maximum number of pairs algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matching

I have two tables of people, containing both males and females. I know their age, race, and interests (yes or no for each variables). The aim is to pair them and set up maximum number of pairs.

There is some criteria for the pairing:

- Their age should be +- 3 years
- Same race first, but difference race is acceptable
- They should have maximum number of common interest

Instead of making many layers of loop and if else condition, is there any faster algorithm to speed up this process?

Comment: This problem is underspecified.  The age is given as a hard restriction, which is fine.  You give two other criteria (race and common interests) but do not specify the relative weight of the two, nor give a minimum value for the matching to be acceptable.  

Stable marriage may apply here if you require the matchings to be stable.  If not, you have a version of the Assignment Problem but you haven't specified the weight function.

Comment: Yes only age is hard restriction. For the other factors, they have same weight that means more common factors are better for pairing up. It will be still okay if they have different race and no common interest, but it must be the last option in pairing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build up the priority set for each male and female according to those criteria and then apply [Stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) algorithm to yield the maximum pairing possible.

For each man, create a separate sorted list(preference list) according to above criteria and vice versa for female. This is just about sorting the male and female array several times with custom comparator.

And now, you have preference list for each male and female, you  are ready to run stable marriage algorithm to get the maximum pair possible. The common pseudo code of stable marriage problem looks like this:

```
function stableMatching {
    Initialize all m ∈ M and w ∈ W to free
    while ∃ free man m who still has a woman w to propose to {
       w = first woman on m’s list to whom m has not yet proposed
       if w is free
         (m, w) become engaged
       else some pair (m', w) already exists
         if w prefers m to m'
            m' becomes free
           (m, w) become engaged 
         else
           (m', w) remain engaged
    }
}
```

If you implement the algorithm properly, the time complexity will be `O(nlogn)`on average case and `O(n^2)` in worst case.